# ExcelWriter , PandaDataFrame, creating new file upon existing one

Tags: python, excel, pandas, beautifulsoup

General trick is that I scrape a website and collect data from it and store in a Panda Data Frame which then I extract to an "Example Sheet" in "Already existing Excel file with existing sheets in it". Everything goes smoothly, the Data is inserted and all.
The question is : is it possible to also create a new file in excel? Meaning that I have a template in excel file which lacks data, I insert that data using my python script and want to save it as a new file while keeping the existing template intact.
Is there a way to it?

Using Beautiful soup, ExcelWriter , PandaDataFrame, Requests,openpyxl

Ive been looking through many threads but didn't find an answer to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course.
eg:

1. Read the template: new = pd.read_excel('....')
2. Insert the data into the read with the help of DataFrame.
3. Save the DataFrame with a new name: new.to_excel('newfile.xlsx')

If you share the template, we will explain it better.